# How to hide the content when page is load using java script in odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, html, odoo-8

I want to hide the all the content when page is load.
It work on icon when i click on icon it is hiding the content but i need to hide the content when page is load here is my java script code,

```
$(document.body).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.hide_class_name').hide();
})
    $('.icon_class_name').on('click', function(event) {        
        $('.hide_class_name').toggle('hide');
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(document.body).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.openerp_webclient_container').hide();
  })
});

Comment: This is working now

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the `body` tag which will hide it's content

**CSS**

```
.hideBody{
display:none
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body class = "hideBody">
//Rest of Code
</body>
```

Now you can use `document.readyState` to check if it is `complete` state

**JS**

```
if(document.readyState ==='complete'){
document.getElementsByTagName('body').classList.add("hideBody")
}
```

Use `document.onreadystatechange` to describes the loading state of the document.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(document.readyState ==='complete'){
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').classList.add("hideBody")
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by __nothing__

Comment: can u help me how to do this ?

Comment: it is not reflecting when i run this code i mean to say that